# Make git-crypt exit with error code target file unencrypted

Tags: git, githooks, git-crypt

I'd like to write a git hook such that commit will fail if our `.env` file is not encrypted. However, `git status` always exits with code 0. How can I have this command exit with an error code when the the file is not committed.

```bash
# file encrypted
git-crypt status .env && echo "exit 0" || echo "exit 1"
# encrypted: .env
# exit 0

# file not encrypted
git-crypt status package.json && echo "exit 0" || echo "exit 1"
# not encrypted: package.json
# exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using grep.

```bash
# exit 1 if "not encrypted" found
git-crypt status .env | \
    grep "not encrypted" && \
    >&2 echo ".env not encrypted, can't commit" && \
    exit 1

# exit normally
exit 0
```

Also works on multiple files.

```bash
git-crypt status .env package.json | \
    grep "not encrypted" && \
    >&2 echo "files not encrypted, can't commit"
# not encrypted: package.json
# files not encrypted, can't commit
```